# Find similarities between 2 signals

Tags: signal-analysis, optimization, doa

Is there any heuristic method to find metrics, similarities between two signals?
I am not talking about correlation.

Comment: Correlation reveals the linear relationship between two signals. Since you already excluded correlation, what relationship are you then looking for?

Comment: **Correlation** is a **waveform** based similarity measure between signals. And it's very a low level comparison. However, depending on the signal type and application domains, there are different (high-level) interpretations of the term *similar* as well. For example, topological similarities are computed during object-image recognition tasks... Such as morphological similarity between a base object and its morphed versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing multiple signals for similarity](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54970/comparing-multiple-signals-for-similarity)

Comment: @DanBoschen I am looking for measuring the total amplitude, time-shifts, and waveform differences.

Comment: @Blobmou what you describe is a correlation. No matter how little you like that.